# Access table linked to SharePoint Library will not refresh

Tags: infopath, access

I have an Access table linked to SharePoint Library of InfoPath forms that will not refresh the Data in the data sheet view of Access.

I have tried all of the options found in File-> Options-> Current Database -> "Caching Web Services and SharePoint Tables". The "Refresh List" item of the Right click Context menu -> "More Options" does not work.

The only thing that works is to quit Access completely and then then go through the "relink and login" process again. Very annoying!

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would place a VBA event module in a form (can't tie event modules to tables in access) that you commonly use.

```
  Private Sub Form_Load()
          CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table1Name").RefreshLink
          CurrentDb.TableDefs("Table2Name").RefreshLink
  End Sub
```